# Debugging Android databases on the real phone

Tags: android

I'm trying to debug an android application's database on a real phone. Where can i find any individual application's databases on a real android phone?

Similar to `/data/databases` on the emulator i tried searching under the `/data` on my atrix, and i don't find anything under it and i would like to debug databases on the real device.

A second question is does the contact app stores the data at google servers (right / wrong). I beleive this would be the case, but was wondering if they also cache the contact databases in every individual phone to speed up access. please correct me if i'm wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the databases folder is still there on your real phone, but you don't have access to it due to permissions. Database files can only be accessed by the app that owns them so you can't browse all of them unless you have root access.

The contact app stores data on your phone's internal memory so that you can access it without an internet connection. Some android devices (e.g. tabs) do not have internet access, and it's possible to query your contacts list using these devices.

Comment: Ahh!!.. now i see one reason why i should root my phone :) .. thanks though !!

Comment: You can also try storing the database file on the external storage... then, you should be able to copy the file over to your computer and do whatever you want with it.